# hold down key instead of re-pressing

Tags: volume, modifier

i'm using this script to change the volume on my computer

## Q::Send {Volume_Up 6}

## A::Send {Volume_Down 6}

which does almost exactly what i want it to, however i would like to hold down the windows key and press Q or A to raise or lower the volume repetitively instead of re-pressing the windows key each time as it is now.

any help is appreciated!